# How to cache on CloudFlare images that are served to client as JSON?

Tags: cdn, cache, cloudflare

I am using a gallery on my website that gets list of images from a JSON sent by a php script. So, the javascript gallery calls PHP backend and it replies with complex JSON where images are specified as object fields. These fields not necessarily include full URLs, merely a path to needed images.

I'd like to use Cloudflare and want these images to be cached there.

How I could learn whether these are cached or not, and make sure that these would be cached and not considered some sort of dynamic content?

Answer (score 1):

It is important to note that we only [cache certain file extensions](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200172516-What-file-extensions-does-CloudFlare-cache-for-static-content-) by default.

You can, however, use [PageRules](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200168306-Is-there-a-tutorial-for-Page-Rules-) to extend CloudFlare's caching.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! How I can be sure that my particular files are cached? If these are not cached for some reason, how I can make them cached?